# Word choice in an acronym definition: (for/in short/shorts) or (shortly)

Tags: word-choice

Suppose you have the following acronym

> Meaningless Random Words Acronym (MRWA)

Which one of these expressions is the most accurate?

- Meaningless Random Words Acronym (MRWA, for shorts);
- Meaningless Random Words Acronym (MRWA, for short);
- Meaningless Random Words Acronym (MRWA, in short);
- Meaningless Random Words Acronym (MRWA, shortly);
- (something else?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a style guide? In [APA](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/21/), abbreviations are introduced like this:

> When abbreviating a term, use the full term the first time you use it, followed immediately by the abbreviation in parentheses.
>
> > According to the American Psychological Association (APA), abbreviations are best used only when they allow for clear communication with the audience.

If you're not using a style guide, then "for short" is what you want to use. [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/for_short) gives this definition:

> **for short** as an abbreviation or nickname: *the File Transfer Protocol, or ftp for short.*

Answer (score 0):

The clearest & most understood version would be

Meaningless Random Words Acronym (MRWA, for short)

You could also shorten it to:

Meaningless Random Words Acronym (MRWA) and be understood

Comment: Downvoters, please help the new user by explaining what you think could be improved here. This seems to answer the question.